# Display Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am using custom post types in a theme optimized for web radios (custom theme). I added a custom post type called "Radio Shows" and registered two custom taxonomies: one hierarchical (like default "categories", I named it GENRE) and the other is not (like "tags", I named it INSTRUMENTS).

I've managed to get that custom post type's posts displayed in index.php with the rest of the default post type's posts and also created a page template that displays only the custom post type's posts (Radio Shows).
It works fine, I can see them being displayed normally, in correct order etc. What's not being displayed in both pages (index & template page dedicated to custom post type) is the custom taxonomies.

In default posts, inside the loop are being displayed:

1. CATEGORIES
2. TITLE
3. THUMBNAILS
4. CONTENT
5. TAGS.

What I want to achieve is to get GENRE & INSTRUMENT custom taxonomies displayed in the place that CATEGORIES & TAGS do in default post types.

Normally I should tell you what I have tried so far... well, I tried at least 20 ways I found on several tutorial websites so it's difficult to list them. None of them worked for me.

Comment: What is the exact name you used to register the post type and the taxonomies?

Comment: radio_show is the name of the post type and genre/instruments for the taxonomies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `the_terms()`:

```
the_terms( $id, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = ', ', $after = '' )
```

So in your loop:

```
if ( 'radio-shows' === get_post_type() )
{
    the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'genre' );
    the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'instruments' );
}
else
{
    the_category();
    the_tags();
}
```

Comment: Toscho thanks for the answer. Unfortunately only the ELSE works as it should in default post type posts. I get nothing in custom post type posts.
EDIT: WORKS LIKE A CHARM! GOD BLESS YOU TOSCHO! THANKS A LOT!!!